# Ayuda con el metodo buscar c# mvc razor

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

que tal amigo recurro nuevamente a ustedes para poder solucionar un problema que creo es simple pero no he podido dar con al solución.

1- Estoy usando el componente cosen para poder ingresar varios datos a un formulario de busqueda que contiene 2 dropdownlist.

2.- pueden estar llenos los 2 dropdownlist o en su caso unicamente uno de los 2

3.- el modelo que uso es el siguiente

```
 [NotMapped]
public class SearchProcedimiento:MtoProcedimiento
{
    public int? Page { get; set; }

    public IPagedList<MtoProcedimiento> result_MtoProcedimientos { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<MtoProcedimiento> ListProcedimientos { get; set; }

    public int[] itemLicitaciones { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<MtoTipoEvento> ListTipoEventos { get; set; }

    public int[] itemTipoEventos { get; set; }


}
```

4. la problemática empieza cuando en el controller hago la consulta de la siguiente manera.

   var list = from t in db.MtoProcedimientos
                   where (model.itemLicitaciones.Contains((int)t.MtoProcedimientoId) ||
                          model.itemTipoEventos.Contains((int)t.MtoTipoEventoId))
                   select t;

bien resulta que cuando los 2 dropdownlist están llenos hace la consulta, pero cuando uno de los 2 esta vació me manda el siguiente error.

```
No se puede crear un valor de constante NULL de tipo 'System.Int32[]'. Solo se admiten tipos de entidad, tipos de enumeración o tipos primitivos en este contexto.
```

pienso que es porque, el array esta null, como podria validar para poder en caso de que el array este vacio poner en la posicion 0 del array el valor "0" para que considere todos los registros en mi consulta.

o podrian darme una ayuda de como generar esta consulta.

muchas gracias saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Si no interpreté mal tu problema, bastaría con que valides que `mtoProcedimientoId` o `MtoTipoEventoId` sean nulos, yo probaría lo siguiente, perdón si hay error de sintaxys, que no tengo IDE a mano

```
var list = from t in db.MtoProcedimientos
where 
((t.MtoProcedimientoId == null || model.itemLicitaciones.Contains((int)t.MtoProcedimientoId))
 || 
(t.MtoTipoEventoId == null || model.itemTipoEventos.Contains((int)t.MtoTipoEventoId)))
select t;
```

Eso sí `MtoProcedimientoId`  y `MtoTipoEventoId` deben ser de algún tipo `<Nullable>`

Espero que sea lo que buscabas! sino corregime en los comentarios y le seguimos buscando la vuelta!

Saludos y éxitos!

Comment: que tal juan muchas gracias lo que quiero validar son los model.itemLicitaciones y model.itemTipoEventos, ya que t.MtoProcedimientoId y t.MtoTipoEventoId siempre tienen registros en la base de datos

Comment: Tendrías que aplicar la misma metodología que utilicé en mi respuesta, primero, consultar primero si es `null`, y luego realizar la lógica de `LINQ` de modo que si es efectivamente `null` pase sin verificar la segunda condición, me explico?

Comment: que tal juan muchas gracias, ya le di muchas vueltas al asunto y no he podido solucionarlo, podrías darme una idea mas clara, muchas gracias.

Comment: @HoracioXochitemol , en los casos en los que no sabes si una variable va a ser `null` como en este caso, lo ideal, es hacer un `if` que contenga un `OR` de modo que primero evalúe la condición de `null`, y en caso de cumplirse de verdadero sin necesidad de evaluar la segunda condición (que en tu caso daría error), en cambio, si no es `null` evaluaría la segunda condición, de su `.Contains()`  me entendes?

Comment: pues resulta que ya quedo, lo solucione con los siguiente.

Answer (score 0):

no se si sea la mejor solución pero lo que hice fue cambiar el código de la consulta a lo siguiente.

```
  var list = from t in db.MtoProcedimientos
                   where model.itemLicitaciones.Contains(t.MtoProcedimientoId) ||
                         model.itemTipoEventos.Contains(t.MtoTipoEventoId)  
                   select t;
```

ahora en el script desde donde lo llamo quedo así.

```
$('#NewSearchResumen').submit(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var itemlicitaciones = $('#itemLicitaciones').val();
    var itemtipoeventosventos = $('#itemTipoEventos').val();


    if (itemlicitaciones != null || itemtipoeventosventos != null) {

        var NewModel = {
            ItemLicitaciones: itemlicitaciones,
            itemTipoEventos: itemtipoeventosventos
        };

        var booksResumen = $("#booksResumen");

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: _urlBase + "Procedimientos/ResumenProcedimientos",
            contenType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
            data: { model: NewModel, "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() },
            datatype: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (objeto) {
                openLoad();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                closeLoad();                    
                booksResumen.html('');
                booksResumen.html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                closeLoad();
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(status);
            }
        });


    }
    else {
        sweetAlert("Oops...", 'Seleccione criterios de busqueda validos', "error");
    }
});
```

ya hice pruebas y me manda la vista parcial; sin embargo en la consola me muestra el siguiente error.

```
TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function[Saber más] bootstrap.validate.js:28:13
```

onFormSubmit
http://localhost:57331/Scripts/bootstrap.validate.js:28:13
dispatch
http://localhost:57331/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js:4429:15
add/elemData.handle
http://localhost:57331/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js:4116:6